# How do I enable ESLint for VS Code while receiving 'running scripts is disabled' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

eslint is not working!

i write `npm install eslint -g`
and then when i trying to check  `eslint --version` it throws an error
`eslint : File C:\Users\Hp laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\eslint.ps1 cannot be loaded  because running scripts is disabled on this system.`

i want to enable eslint for vs code

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with sudo? if you are using linux you need to run 'sudo npm install eslint -g' if you are using windows run the cmd prompt with admin mode.